# Merge request, after seeing how the the other half experiences SO

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

I ran an experiment after seeing a few posts on Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

Most notably [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256694/217863) which suggested:

> Create a new profile (low rep points) that can be recognized as female
>   and participate. Take notice of **how you feel with this profile** and if
>   your experience is different. Don't try to ***act*** like you think a woman
>   would act, just do your thing and see if you get a different response.

I created a new profile that could be recognized as female, using the name Sarah Jane.
<sub>([A bad reference to a song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB9DSWxtsgU) by The Dead Milkmen, a satirical '80s punk rock band)</sub>

I used the profile casually for 41 days, posted 8 answers, a few comments, and a couple of edits.

The results of my, admittedly limited, experiment was that it is kinda lame to be a new user. Not being able to vote, close vote, and so on really limits ones experience on the site.

On the other hand I didn't personally see or feel any sexism in any of the exchanges I had as Sarah. Feel free to peruse [Sarah Jane's activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930928/sarah-jane?tab=activity&sort=all) perhaps I missed something.

This led me to the conclusion that sexism *may* be a problem on the network, but it isn't as common or pervasive as some have suggested.

---

Clarification of intent:

To be clear the reason I decided to run this experiment was that I was a little unsettled by the accusations of a sexist culture on SO.

It wasn't something that I had ever witnessed on SO, and I figured it may worth examining further. Perhaps sexism was common, I just wasn't seeing it because I wasn't in the position to see it.

Comment: Too late now, but you should have tried posting questions.

Comment: Hey, apaul, you sound pretty hot.  Can u send pix 2 mi?

Comment: @Will too late to put a thumb on the scale... and really why would you want to?

Comment: Interesting edit rejection. Which particular "half" are you talking about, by the way? You didn't use a cute picture on your profile. Not the ones you're sending @Will, but, you know, something cute.

Comment: Plus where does the "merge" come into this? You request a merge through the "contact us" at the bottom of the page. Woops. I said bottom.

Comment: @BillWoodger Figured making the experiment public, and perhaps even reproducible, might be good for the over all discussion of the subject.

Comment: @1999 Posting questions is not necessarily a "common activity" for a user, especially a high rep one. For example, the main account only has 9.

Comment: @1999 I didn't ask any questions because I didn't have any at the time, and figured contriving one just to post one would be manipulating the experiment too much.

Comment: @apaul34208 Making up who you are is okay but making up a question to get data/responses goes to far?

Comment: @NathanOliver Wouldn't a contrived question be a poor question by definition?

Comment: @NathanOliver It's called science.  When doing an experiment you need to have *only one variable*, and strive to keep everything else constant.  If you have multiple variables throughout the experiment, then you cannot determine whether, or how, any particular variable affected the outcome.  If he varies both his profile, and his posting habits, then he wouldn't be able to tell if his differing experiences were because of his profile, or because of his differing asking habits.

Comment: @apaul34208 Not *by definition*; some people do manage to ask good contrived questions, but it's unusual for them to be good.  There's a *tendency* for them to be bad, even if it's not a *requirement*.

Comment: @Servy but he did change both variables.  he has asked questions in his normal profile.  if you don't ask questions the the "girl" profile then how can you compare the results?

Comment: @NathanOliver I have asked a few questions on my normal profile, but few and far between, only when I was honestly stuck on something.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET My point was that one doesn't really get to see the site through a new user's eyes (of whatever gender) without posting questions.

Comment: To not be too critical, this is perhaps a Proof of Concept, rather than an experiment. Looking at the user you link to, for their experience on SO, I can see nothing remotely approaching any type of "ism" at all. You'd need to find "obviously female" examples and check those out, if you find stuff, operate in those tags, as there may be specifics. Stuff like that.

Comment: @NathanOliver He used the new profile to interact with the site exactly as he would have if he didn't have a different profile (to the best of his abilities, given the differences in permissions through rep).  Meaning he asked questions when he had questions to asked, answered questions that he knew the answer to and would have otherwise answered, etc.  It's important that he use the site (as close to) as he would have if he were using his main account.  If he wouldn't have asked a question on his main account during that period of time, he shouldn't with the other account.

Comment: @1999 Sure, but then its a "new user"/"bad at asking questions" problem as opposed to how we react to a *good* user of a different gender.

Comment: @1999 You can see the site through the eyes of an active answerer (which is what apaul is in his normal account).  He's not going to (nor is he trying to) see the site through the eyes of someone coming to SO to ask questions, because that's not how *he* (typically) uses the site.

Comment: Is this really about a sexist *culture*, which in my book describes something widespread enough that you see it daily? Moderation must work fast to clean that stuff up then, I can honestly say I've never seen an instance of that yet in the few years I've been hanging around.

Comment: I couldn't see Sarah Jane's activity tab. I got "Page Not Found". Thanks for doing this, though and taking the request seriously.

Comment: @JuliaAnneJacobs Sorry about that, after the accounts were merged "Sarah's activity" was merged into my primary account.

Comment: @JuliaAnneJacobs while I have you, the experiment prompted some enlightening conversations in my personal life, it was a really helpful experience over all. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Here is how to get your accounts merged.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

As far as your experiment goes: I'm glad you didn't have a bad experience. I'd just ask you to please be careful not to let your results convince you to disregard the negative experiences women have actually had on the network.

I find it much more informative to listen to the people who have had certain types of interactions here than to try and re-create the interactions in order to see them for myself.

Comment: I have seen instances where comment threads under questions discuss the "cuteness" of the poster rather than the quality of the question. Entirely agree that just because one person doesn't experience something it doesn't mean it doesn't happen.

Comment: @TZHX I have to be honest, I know that there is an implied bias and sexism to software dev.... but THAT bad?... wow...

Comment: @Patrice I would blame Internet anonymity before the job field of the posters, and I've not seen it *often* in my years of trolling the site, but yes.

Comment: @TZHX fair enough. At least the "not often" part makes me feel better :P

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, connectivity problems... I surely didn't intend to minimize anyone's experience positive or negative. It just seemed that the network was being portrayed in an unnecessarily negative way and I wanted to see for myself. My sense of things is that sexism is relatively rare on SO and when it does rear its ugly head it gets moderated rather quickly. But when bad things do, occasionally, happen people tend to act like they happen "all the time" and that the moderation team is some how complicit, or unaware of the problem.

Comment: I thought offering another perspective may add something to the conversation.

Comment: @apaul34208 I think you've hit on one of the great things about our network: things from raging abuse to just irrelevant chatter get shut down pretty quickly here, which does help keep the problem at bay. I think, from personal experience, that when folks say "I can't believe this went wrong AGAIN", they don't mean that it happens on SO all the time; they mean that it happens to them all the time on the internet, and the SO event is just the latest in a line of experiences.

Comment: I guess I can understand that perspective... The internet can be an abrasive place. But I've always found SE to be an exception to that. By and large SE tends to be inviting and accepting, it gets under my skin to be painted with such a broad brush. Just trying to point out that bad things happening is the exception, rather than the rule.

Comment: It certainly is the exception, especially here, @apaul34208. I think we do a great job of shutting this stuff down just because of our engine and the focused nature of our community. I'll be clear that I don't think you've done anything wrong here. I just want to leave space for people who *have* had bad experiences and make sure we all trust and believe them - and help improve their experience as much as we can.