# Why was this (gender-issue related) answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, gender

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382694

Based on a discussion of the comments of [another self-deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382730) answer, this answer was deleted by a community manager, and someone (a mod? A CM?) was quoted saying: "**This isn't an argument we wish to give you a platform to make**, and we have no obligation to do so".

From my admittedly limited perspective, it sounds like that this post was deleted because it made a "forbidden argument", rather than being something that was against the CoC. However, this quote may be in reference to a comment, rather than an argument made in the answer. It also might not have been made by the entity that deleted the answer.

Assuming it was the "forbidden argument", what was it?
Why was this answer deleted?

I would hate to accidentally make such an argument out of ignorance, and suffer mod/CM wrath because of it.

**EDIT:**

Now that I can see the answer, thanks to the image, it seems like the arguments made here are little different than those in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367176/773737), such as "**biological differences**", "**I don't see a problem** that needs to be solved", and "If fewer women choose to become programmers, **so what?**"

So I'm having trouble spotting the "forbidden argument" that exists in one answer, but not the other.

Comment: @davidism That assumes that the "someone" that was quoted here was the same person that deleted the answer. That might not be true

Comment: Try this argument:  what makes it worthy of keeping, exactly?  I don't see anything in there which is constructive or really motivates a positive discussion about this matter.

Comment: @Makoto I couldn't tell you, as I can't see it. From my perspective, it seems like someone crossed a political line by bringing up a "forbidden argument", hence the question.

Comment: @davidism:  This is more for the sake of discussing the specific answer.  We're not allowing the OP of this answer any air-time nor are we discussing the subject matter.  We're discussing the post, and the post **only**.   Furthermore the OP couldn't see this and thus couldn't form a complete perspective on the answer.  If the post isn't good then the discussion is going to be pretty quick, isn't it?  (I also didn't see a comment to the OP's effect on *this* answer...)

Comment: @davidism:  Where?  I'm not seeing that in the comment chain.

Comment: @davidism: To be totally fair, if they wanted to remove the answer, employees have the power to *completely* remove it. Or at the very least, do what they do for "spam/abusive" posts (edit them down to nothing, with a link to the history if you really want to read it). Leaving it deleted means that it's visible for 10k+ rep users.

Comment: Right - echoing Nicol's sentiment, I wouldn't have linked to it if it was genuinely not something that the CMs wanted us to discuss.

Comment: Ah - I found the comment - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309908/declining-numbers-of-women-in-programming-what-can-so-do-to-help/382694#comment686669_382709.  So, fair play; I'll remove the image.

Comment: Looks like a repost.  More things make sense now @davidism.  I'll just compile my thoughts into an answer on it now since I finally have all the context I need.

Comment: @Makoto the image still exists in the edit history, but I suppose you could raise a special flag for that.

Comment: Not sure if there is or isn't a "forbidden argument" but that deleted answer wasn't constructive at all. The analogy with "pregnant men"? It seems to be trolling to me.

Comment: @Houseman You can't really compare the deleted post with the one you linked. In the latter, the poster actually gives scientific sources for their claims instead of just dropping a long rant of personal opinions. There's no denying that men and women are different biologically. If that somehow has an impact on the choice of career isn't really something that average Joe can/should speculate about. But If there's scientific research leading to such conclusions then of course we must be able to discuss that.

Comment: @Lundin So the only difference is that one cited sources, while the other didn't?

Comment: @Houseman The main difference is that one is subjective and the other is objective. Objective, open-minded discussion = good. Subjective personal opinions = bad.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There was no discernable good-faith attempt at contributing to the discussion. Multiple users, staff members *and* moderators felt that the 'answer' was barely more than an incendiary rant, and I fully agreed. There was just *so* much wrong with it that it wasn't worth saving, and comments strongly indicated that any additional criticism of the views expressed wouldn't be met favorably. So, I deleted it, hoping that the strong evidence of contention, along with the down votes, along with the fact that it was removed would be sufficient.

I've been doing this for quite a while (8+ years), it's *not* a stretch to think that should have done it.

But it didn't. The answer was re-posted, exactly as before, and it was *again* quickly obvious that the person who wrote it wasn't interested in having a discussion about what was wrong with it. At this point it's becoming clear that they're more interested in the effect their 'point' is having rather than the point itself, so I left a very strong comment.

I completely stand behind all actions I took.

Comment: I'm curious since I'm internally unsure about how such things could be best handled without giving people who were only interested in rants a persecution complex: Do you think having that answer out in the open, but thoroughly downvoted and refuted would be a valid choice as well, or would that amount to bait for people to get lost in needless and unuseful discussion?

Comment: Generally agree though, one of the advantages of a private platform is you don't need to entertain every argument ad nauseam.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that the comment, shorn of context, made me jump straight to a bad faith interpretation of those actions.  When explaining those actions, though, it seems far more reasonable.  I apologize for the accusation I made.

Comment: @Magisch A "head on a stake" can be problematic for many reasons. The answer was incendiary and had no use other than making people angry. I can't conceive a well-articulated version of that argument lacking hyperbole and fallacy (thus, also likely to be very incendiary), but I wouldn't delete it if it somehow appeared simply because I disagreed with it, I'd leave a comment saying I speak for the company and we disagree with it. I don't know if you can make an argument with facts that just don't exist, so it would depend on what someone pulled out of thin air.

Comment: Fair enough. FWIW I don't disagree with the deletion, having seen a screenshot of the answer. If I'd seen it before the deletion, I may have went for R/A, but generally unsure.

Comment: I don't like this kind of interference, why not let the vote speak ? This action is on the red line.

Comment: @Stargateur Is it just who deleted it that irks you? Having seen it I think it would have either gotten delete voted by users or red flag nuked if left up soon enough. Tim's answer has a point there: It was already headed in that direction

Comment: @Stargateur Us permitting certain things on our platform _can be seen as an endorsement of those things_, however tacit it might be. It is rare, but there are certain kinds of things that we simply _will not_ host, and I submit that it's _those_ things that cross a red line. We are not a government, and we will remove content that violates our code of conduct or does nothing but create disruption.

Comment: @Magisch can you do more simple sentence ? What I want to say is I really don't like censorship even if people say the most stupid thing ever. Delete them, and the discussion stop and hate will just grown alone.

Comment: @Stargateur [It's not censorship](https://xkcd.com/1357/), but I have a feeling that we will disagree on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tim. Personally, I don't see anything that inflammatory with it. I linked a similar answer that appears to make all the same points that this deleted answer did. The only difference is that the deleted answer has no sources cited. The points and the conclusion were the same: "There's no problem".

Comment: @Stargateur Users (not staff, not moderators) are able to delete negatively scored answers if they see fit. It's a 20.000 reputation privilege. This post was before Tim made the executive decision to delete it already heading that way. It's not really censorship, more quality control. Irky viewpoints aside (and there are), this post's quality was sufficiently lacking to support its deletion on those merits alone.

Comment: @Houseman The sarcastic humor, the undertones in the other paragraphs (when you know something is likely to be ill-received, you need to exercise more care in how you defend it), all of the comments (deleted and visible) as well as a _myriad_ of complaints piling up .. this one was different in enough ways that sent it across some lines.

Comment: @Magisch We are on stack overflow meta not stack overflow, negative answer IS NOT about post's quality. (Maybe we should have two separate vote ?)

Comment: @Stargateur It can be both. Posting a trashy rant will get you downvoted, posting disagreeable stuff will too. In this case it was both. Besides being a quite bad argument largely unsupported by reality, it was also an antagonistic rant and borderline rude or abusive.

Comment: I appreciate that you answered here. As already mentioned in the other Q/A: The answer in question was shallow, inconsiderate, and unnecessary. But I don't see how it should have violated the CoC. Therefore, simply deleting it, vaguely talking about an "argument+platform" is problematic. It was just a "bad" answer, and the downvotes already started raining. Deleting it will (yeah, make some people scream "censorship!!11", but) at least give the impression that certain arguments are not allowed, and that there's a questionable amount of ‎arbitrariness in the moderation...

Comment: This is a bad justification for deletion. That answer was relevant to the question, and was no more badly argued, no more bigoted, and no more insulting to the other side, than Jay Hanlon's "welcoming" post or plenty of the commentary that's been posted by Stack Exchange staff. I can't speak to the supposed abusive comments that led to the suspension, since I have not seen them. But, bluntly, it seems to me that this post was treated differently - to the point of threatening suspension over it - primarily because you disagreed with the political beliefs expressed in it. That's not okay.

Comment: The suspension was *fully* justified, @Mark. The comments motivating it were in flagrant violation of the CoC. Regarding the answer itself, I tend to agree with you. When moderating Meta, I try to check my own (strong) political beliefs at the door, and while the site has the right to suppress this material (a la the XKCD), I think it’s important that they tread very lightly in doing so for a variety of reasons. I see what irks Tim and others about it. Yet I wouldn’t have deleted it. I think downvotes send a stronger signal. I also don’t think allowing this to be posted suggests endorsement.

Comment: At the same time, it’s not valuable enough that I think it would be worth another moment arguing over it or protesting its deletion. Tim is a reasonable, level-headed person, and this is *very* far from creating a slippery slope.

Comment: So yeah that answer deserved its deletion. Truth is I'd rather lock the question than deal with it again. It's archival material now anyway.

Comment: Incendiary rants are exactly what one would expect from a question that not only concerns politics, but has a political viewpoint inexorably baked into it. The concept of social engineering to influence a demographic imbalance is very political, so any question that entertains the notion **is undeniably political**. If I asked a question that concerned treating Black users differently, I would expect my question to be punished and not the answers from those outraged by it.

Comment: @Joshua the question is as relevant today as it was in 2015. You don't have to personally deal with the question if you don't like the content matter.

Comment: @gunfulker as the largest programming site of it's type, it's relevant to discuss the influence the site has over the demographics of it's users. Erm, the developer survey in fact focuses on that. The network has made it clear it wants to be inclusive, the question was ahead of its time in fact. It wasn't a political question. Trust me, I'm a highly political person and I know when I'm aiming at a political discussion. The question was aimed at encouraging women to use the site. A problem we have. Women don't like the site and it's hardly surprising why.

Comment: @YvetteColomb "Trust me, I'm a highly political person" I know, that was pretty obvious from your original question. "A problem we have." Thinking demographic differences as a problem **is a political stance**. In the opposing political sphere we find top-down social engineering to be authoritarian, divisive, and almost always counterproductive to it's own goals.

Comment: @gunfulker calling efforts to remove barriers for participation "top down social engineering" is a blatantly uncharitable interpretation of the efforts.

Comment: @Magisch I could just as well say that characterising them as "barriers to participation" is uncharitable to gunfulker. After all, there's no "no women allowed" sign at our door; calling whatever factors lead to lower female participation "barriers" is political spin as much as gunfulker's talk of "top down social engineering" is. Yet this path likely leads to us calling each other out for "uncharitable" language every time we disagree. Better, I think, to simply accept that the language people use to frame sociopolitical issues will naturally reflect their personal views on those issues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191733/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-post-why-was-this-gender-issue-related-answer-dele).

Comment: @TimPost I think it's important to point out that this is, in fact, censorship. It *isn't* an attack on someone's right to free speech though, as you shared. This is a huge distinction. Does your moderation on SO infringe on anyone's free speech? No of course not, but your direct action has, does, and most likely will continue to censor things you don't like to some extent. This is fully your right as community manager, for good and ill. I'm personally hoping for more good than bad - I rather like this place.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave Deleting SPAM is, arguably, censorship as well. Some of my colleagues are more amenable to simply embracing the concept and saying look, _some_ censorship is necessary in order to maintain a thriving, rule-abiding community. I feel the word takes on a very pejorative sense, and speaks _more_ to intent than action when it goes from curation to moderation to _censorship_, so I'm just probably not going to align with your view, as much as I _don't_ disagree with you, if that makes sense?

Comment: I find that xkcd cartoon objectionable. Calling another user an a**hole (even by [analogy](https://xkcd.com/1357/)) because they hold views you consider objectionable doesn't seem very "nice".

Answer (score 11):

So this might take a moment to unpack...

The *original* answer was deleted by a CM because the conversation after the answer was posted started turning downright *hostile*.  As in, the OP decided to comment that this wasn't a constructive answer and didn't contribute anything to the conversation.

But instead of taking the hint about this, it was **reposted**.  *This* is where the CM came in with the comment:

[image]

What happened next is between that person and the moderators.

So, long story short:  the answer posted wasn't exactly constructive or conducive to the conversation, and the follow-up from the post wasn't going to make this into a good discussion, either.  So, it was removed - which is totally justified by the CoC.

Comment: "As in, the OP decided to comment that this wasn't a constructive answer and didn't contribute anything to the conversation." Do you mean "the CM decided to comment..."?

Comment: Actually, it was originally the OP that commented on the answer, which likely kicked things off.  I'm...not going to put a picture in of that comment thread for Reasons™...

Comment: "The original question was deleted by a CM" Do you mean "the original answer"? The question still exists, right?

Comment: Now *that* was a legitimate slip, thanks for catching it.

Comment: Cool. One last thing to help me understand: the OP commented on their OWN answer that "this wasn't a constructive answer and didn't contribute anything to the conversation"?

Comment: The OP of the question commented on the answer in question saying that it wasn't constructive.

Comment: Oh okay, now it makes sense. It seems that the content of the answer wasn't too different from other answers, but I'm relieved that just arguing something like "biological differences" doesn't seem to be forbidden.