# Is Stack Overflow chat a part of Stack Overflow main site?

Tags: discussion

> Is Stack overflow chat only for programming related topics or for others also?

There is a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) named JavaScript on chat.stackoverflow.com. As the name suggests, it's related to programming, but the discussion going-on in the chat room is what I think, not related to programming.

In the room they are discussing about some cars and energies and what not. I am unable to relate all that with the JavaScript programming language.

Is it valid to discuss off-topic stuff on chat.stackoverflow.com like that?

If it's valid than I'm confused, is it a part of Stack Overflow?

If it's not valid and a part of Stack Overflow then that kind of chat must be prohibited, mustn't it?

Or does JavaScript mean something else?

Comment: Ongoing discussion at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366793/recourse-for-inappropriate-stack-overflow-chat-conversation

Comment: Not the same , they are different

Comment: It's about the same chat room as the one that you're talking about. You'll see from that discussion that there is no 100% consensus on what exactly is on topic in a chat room.

Comment: There is javascript technology being used in car industry. So that _could_ be somewhat ... relevant.

Comment: But it's not about those technologies , it's totally different

Comment: Please read the rules of the room mentioned : http://javascriptroom.github.io/rules/ _The room title is JavaScript, which only implies we all have some interest in the language. That does not strictly limit the topic of conversation to JavaScript, and often it is not about JavaScript. Please do not inturrupt and complain about this, if you have a comment about the language toss it in and if someone is interested they will stop and help._

Comment: I cant believe I had to make the same comment twice in meta :P

Comment: They were also talking about  rail routes, is js used in trains?

Comment: \*rail roads. Yes. If the topic stood at only javascript then the chat would be like a desert. If someone calls for aid then it is hard to have a response. By talking about other topics, the area is more like a public plaza. Here, you can get faster response when calling for help. So, if you have a question, you can ask it. Simple.

Comment: @KarelG hummm, looks interesting ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem here is - if you wanted to start a JS conversation, you totally could have, and I'm sure many would join you. You did not though, as well as you did not read the room rules you were pointed at 3 times.

Comment: @SurajRao twice?  Twice so far. stop being so otimistic: there will be plenty of opportunities for more moaning about the JS room members having a life.

Comment: I am surprised why this question was closed as "not seeking input". The input what this question seeks is that is offtopic communication on the Javascript chatroom (in broader sense: on the SO chat) allowed or not. The answer can be yes or no, depending on the community customs and the rules; it should be made clear and this question deserves a reopen.

Comment: @peterh from the comments below the accepted answer it didnt look like OP was looking for a discussion to me. It looked like trolling

Comment: I wasn't trolling , you were the one who gave such examples

Comment: @SurajRao Ok, but I think in this case, the OP should get the answer to the question *what he asked*, and if he is not satisfied with it, it is his problem. Although he seems satisfied now (accepted a +7 scored answer).

Comment: @MasterDarkNight I didnt give any examples except mention the rules

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq

> **What can we chat about?**
>
> This site is an extension of Stack Overflow, so discussion *should* more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.
>
> [...]
>
> When talking in a room, it's polite to stay *roughly on topic for the room*, as defined by the room owners.

Emphasis mine. It's up to the room owners to decide what's on-topic.

Rooms can also have custom rules. This excerpt comes from the [JavaScript room rules](http://rlemon.github.io/so-chat-javascript-rules/):

> The room title is JavaScript, which only implies we all have some interest in the language. That does not strictly limit the topic of conversation to JavaScript, and often it is not about JavaScript. Please do not inturrupt and complain about this, if you have a comment about the language toss it in and if someone is interested they will stop and help.

Comment: Humm , it's more confusing , what's the relation of cars with programming language?  They are discussing about cars ?

Comment: @MasterDarkNight: Heard of _"Fordran"_ or _"Citroën#"_?

Comment: No, what are those ?

Comment: It's no fun if you need to explain the joke: _"Fordran"_ > _"Ford"_ (car brand) + _"Fortran"_, programming language.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well then what's Citroen ?

Comment: What programming language begins with a _"C"_ and ends with a _"#"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus C# and itroen ? What us itroen ?

Comment: @Master are you purposely missing the point (aka trolling) or do you genuinely not understand what we're trying to tell you?

Comment: @MasterDarkNight: That Citroën's new model, a type of car you can't "C".

Comment: What point ?¿ what ?

Comment: Ok folks, we're going nowhere with these cars.

Comment: @halfer thats taken care of https://github.com/JavaScriptRoom/rules/pull/1 :)

Answer (score 12):

It's a chat. Just compare it to the water cooler, cafeteria or any other social area in an office. Often people will chat about work related stuff (let's say JavaScript), but there will be random chit-chat, socializing, etc. as well (like what you apparently noticed when joining the room).

Also, I'm pretty sure there *is* some JavaScript in many modern cars. Hopefully not in critical areas but entertainment systems are getting more and more fancy in cars.

Comment: I agree with you, but I hope there's no Javascript in modern cars...

Comment: Re *"I'm pretty sure there is some JavaScript in many modern cars"*: Yes, if [Atwood's law](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-principle-of-least-power/) holds. And it is [coming into embedded systems](https://www.espruino.com/).