# I got answer-banned because I answered instead of commented, but I cannot comment

Tags: discussion, post-ban, welcoming, blog

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How do you pack a c++ DLL that can still be injected into a game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086649/how-do-you-pack-a-c-dll-that-can-still-be-injected-into-a-game/50086709#50086709)

Just recently, Jay Hanlon had a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1) posted, which concerned the feelings experienced by new and other marginal users on Stack Overflow. Just now, I got answer-banned because someone flagged my answer as "too unimportant" (see link) as to be rated as an answer. I feel that my answer was very relevant to the topic. I also would have liked to *comment* instead of *answer*, because – of course – I understood the preliminary level of my "answer" (request).

Now I feel a little – very much – awkward, because I tried to help and also to increase my worth to the community and instead got further blown to the limits of the sky.

Now I am doomed not to be able to do anything – answer-bans do not lift themselves and my questions are rated as not-important enough.

Comment: One misplaced answer will not trigger a ban.

Comment: Your answer is asking clarifications from the user. That is indeed what comments are for. I get it's unfortunate to not be able to comment until you have the rep for it, but the system is working as intended.... The ban isn't someone who decided to ban you. It's that the algorithm weighting your contributions thinks that your next answer is unlikely to be great. And you have to have other answers if you are answer banned. You don't get a ban from one post.

Comment: @Patrice I do understand that; I also stated that I know. I am trying to highlight a design flaw in this structure, which seems to be known in the upper floors of the hierarchy. Thank you for pointing out the problem again.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite what problem? You posted a non-answer as an answer, got a bad reception, and tripped an automated ban algorithm. If I try to enter my house by a window, my alarm will ring. It's not a flaw....

Comment: Related: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: So you knowingly broke the rules and you want your account to be unbanned because you "feel a little – very much – awkward" and you think this is a reasonable request because of that blog post, have I got that right?

Comment: @Oleg I'm sure you have.  That blog is forever going to be a sword, wielded by anyone who breaks the rules, feels slighted or has some other agenda that is not promoting good software development, and directed against anyone who is volunteering time to try to moderate:(

Comment: Incidentally, you assisted some user with the name 'Suicide Cheats' who, it seems is engaged in hacking GTA via DLL injection.  Are you sure that not legally actionable by GTA/Rockstar?  You should check with a lawyer.

Comment: The blog post does not contain an invitation to blatantly ignore the core values of the site. Don't pretend it is. That is rude to the current user base.

Comment: This question is "about policies and community decisions" and hence on-topic per https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta voted to reopen.

Comment: @rene You're right, it doesn't say it's okay to ignore the rules, it just says that it's inappropriate to inform other people when they are ignoring the rules, which is close enough to the same thing for practical purposes.  Saying that the site is still going to have quality standards, it's just going to refuse to allow people to actually enforce them or tell other people that they should be following them is not really meaningfully different from just not having quality standards in the first place.

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: @philipxy Discussion meta posts are meant as a starting point, and this evidently does start a discussion.

Comment: That blog post did not go well at all!

Comment: People get 10 or 20 upvotes after putting much effort into their questions. But you have taught us how to achieve hundreds of downvotes.

Comment: Then just don't say anything, sorry, it's how stackoverflow works. With all pros and cons.

Answer (score 108):

> Just now, I got answer-banned because someone flagged my answer as "too unimportant" (see link) as to be rated as an answer.

No, your answer was deemed to not be an answer. And it wasn't; it was a comment.

That this led to an answer-ban is not the fault of the person who (correctly) flagged your comment-as-an-answer. Nor is it the fault of the people who (correctly) downvoted your answer. It's *your* fault for repeated violations of our quality standards for answers.

And to make sure you understand, you don't get answer banned for one answer. It takes *repeated* violations to get a ban. That this was your last straw is not the fault of the people (correctly) downvoting your answer.

> Now I feel a little – very much – awkward, because I tried to help and also to increase my worth to the community and instead got further blown to the limits of the sky.

Then you should have learned to help within the limits of the powers you have. If you're not allowed to comment, that means what you wanted to say as a comment *cannot be said*. If that comment were complete enough to be an answer, it shouldn't be posted as a comment. And if it isn't, then it shouldn't be posted as an answer.

You should have just moved on to something else. There are plenty of questions on the site that *don't* need comments before you could answer them.

> I am trying to highlight a design flaw in this structure, which seems to be known in the upper floors of the hierarchy.

Not allowing you to comment is not a "design flaw". We have [a reason why commenting requires 50 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). And it is not a "design flaw" to prevent people from circumventing this restriction by using answers as comments. Answers are for answers to the question. People should be able to read an answer and actually get an answer. Allowing users to use answers as comments works against that.

None of this is a "design flaw". You wanted to do something, what you wanted was not allowed by your current reputation, so you did something wrong instead of accepting your limitations. Punishing this behavior is not a "design flaw", anymore than arresting someone for mugging people is a "design flaw".

Just because you believe that you ought to be able to do a thing doesn't mean you can do that thing.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.
 – It still does not make any great sense, though, because it simply leads to people either deleting their profile or just leaving altogether. Also, your answer very much feels like a comment.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: how bad is the ban? Is it a forever ban? A temporary ban? If temporary, then how long?

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: "*it simply leads to people either deleting their profile or just leaving altogether.*" But... you repeatedly violated our quality standards. You were given several opportunities to make good contributions to the site, and you made *bad* contributions. We were welcoming, but only up to the point where it was clear that you weren't contributing *positively* to the site. We aren't going to sacrifice quality on the altar of making one individual happy.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it says [We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). It does not specify any further detail.
I have to say, I refrained from just deleting lowly rated answers and questions, because I don't want to simply give in to peer pressure – if something was not worth telling, I would not have posted in the first place.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: Basically, imagine you're a house-guest. Every downvote is someone telling you "hey, that thing you just did? Even though you think that's OK, it's really not OK." Eventually, when you do enough "not OK" things, the other people in the house tell you to leave. That's not being un-"welcoming"; it's simply requiring people to contribute positively.

Comment: @NicolBolas I tried to make good contributions. The average who actually looked at them rated them badly. I hope you do not speak for everyone on stackexchange, because you seem not to have the faintest idea,  what Jay Hanlon (see above) was talking about. I understand it is hard to walk in a newcomers shoes, as everything seems very simple.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: "*I tried to make good contributions.*" I understand and appreciate that you *tried*. But you failed to do so; a lot (again, one bad post does not get you banned). We cannot keep allowing a person to screw up over and over again until they get it right. If we want a high-quality site, people who have failed to positively contribute have to be shown the door.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite We all were walking in newcomers shoes once, so we understand. Can you give some more context to your answer history? Did you post comments as answers before? Do you have deleted answers? You should have gotten comments from review queue if answers did get deleted due to being "not an answer", did you receive messages like that?

Comment: @ModusTollens I never deleted any of my answers or questions. I just once – in this instance – got this message.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: the Jay Hanlon blog has been read by most all of us, and has been debated up and down on the meta site. Believe me when I say that most of us are quite aware of it, and it does expose an ongoing issue of how to be welcoming to newbies while maintaining site quality and ability of the site to self-moderate. This discussion will continue to develop over time, and tweaks to the site continually are being made to provide as good a balance as possible.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite Go to https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2f and let SO employees know that you think that you should be allowed to post comments as answers indefinitely because of that blog post.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite The strange thing is that there is no way you would get a ban because of _one_ bad answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The rating of this post here alone exemplifies the issue very well I guess.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: no, not at all. On meta we vote on several things, including whether or not we agree with the premise of the poster. Many disagree with your premise which is their right to express. The voting on this question is not a vote against *you* personally.

Comment: Votes on meta do flow more freely. That is because they cost no rep. It's also because they indicate disagreement. That people disagree with you does not mean it's hostile or unwelcoming. You actually have 5 'high rep' users who comment to help you out....that seems not hostile to me...

Comment: @Mistercookiebite Downvotes on this question possibly reflect that users don't agree with your post. You should not post comments as answers, and posts doing that risk downvotes and deletion. That's the site working as intended.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you throw out new members with this kind of attitude, you will not be able to get new blood into the veins of your great site. Keep in mind, that you made a lot more history than anyone starting off just now. You might also have had it easier, as the difficulty level from then to now certainly grew a lot. It is always expected, to already know everything that once had been answered in one aspect or the other.

Comment: @Patrice I do not feel any different on the meta site than on the main site. It feels very hostile indeed.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: then maybe it's time to walk away, if only temporarily. This site is not the be all and end all, and you definitely don't want to get too wrapped up in it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how is it not against me personally? I tried to raise the issue – with little success I assume. 
I never walk away, just because some people disagree.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: exactly, it's not against *you*. It's against your post -- we disagree with its premise and most believe that the site is working as intended. Don't take that personally.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite I can appreciate that is a feeling, indeed. But no one shut you down, insulted or berated you. We just disagreed with you and explained why.... You say it yourself. 'people disagreed'. So anything less than 'yes you are 100% right' would be hostile? How can we express our disagreement without it being taken personally?

Comment: @Patrice I most certainly wonder, why you make a point of it. I understand you do not think my comment is worth the while – still I raised the issue and I do not think my goal has been reached up to now.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: OK, so you say that this reception is "hostile". What would *not* be a "hostile" reception to you? Is agreement with you the only non-"hostile" response? Because agreement is equivalent to saying that we don't care about good contributions. Describe how we could not be "hostile" to you while still relating the substance of our posts (ie: that you did something bad and were punished appropriately).

Comment: @ModusTollens I see, that I have should not commented instead of answered – still I had no possibility to comment in this post. I just wanted to help the guy solve his issue.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: "*I just wanted to help the guy solve his issue.*" ... so? You weren't able to. Just move on to someone else's issue.

Comment: @NicolBolas It would be a start not to downvote a disagreement with your contributions. Also, we're still just commenting under your answer, which is – very roughly spoken – merely more than a dismissal of my issue altogether. We're on Meta, not on the actual SO.

Comment: @nicolbolas Of course I was able to. Until I got purged for formal reasons. As you may already know, I cannot move to anyones issue, because –you may recall – I am answer-banned.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: "*Of course I was able to. Until I got purged for formal reasons.*" So what you're saying is that you just want to help people, our rules be damned. Our rules are what make SO what it is. And if you can't follow them, then there are plenty of new users who can. We're not hostile to new users; we're against people who think the rules don't apply to them.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite You did not "get purged for formal reasons". You posted an answer that was not an answer in the context of SO. It probably got flagged, went through the review queue and got deleted. But for you to get banned this or something similar _must have happened before_ and you should have gotten some notice when it did.

Comment: But see that's the thing. You say the reception here is hostile. How would we express disagreement without you seeing it as hostile? This is the point I am trying to get. With the blog post a lot of users are complaining about hostility. I am trying to get better, and understand how to be ,not hostile' while still being enabled to speak my mind about these issues.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: If enforcing community standards you don't agree with is hostile, then we are going to have to be hostile. And if that means that new users who won't follow the rules get turned away, that is a sacrifice I'm willing to accept.

Comment: @Patrice It might also be quite interesting, how nobody seems to care about the actual question. That might be also interpreted as hostile. Together with the fact, that there seem to be just two sides – right and wrong.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite: "*nobody seems to care about the actual question*" That's because your question has been dealt with. What was done is perfectly valid; there's no problem in our rules or the enforcement thereof. You're simply declaring that to be incorrect.

Comment: @NicolBolas "If enforcing community standards you don't agree with is hostile, then we are going to have to be hostile" dichotomy!!!

Comment: @mistercookiebite but in my mind what happened is proper. I expressed this already in comments. None of my comments are belittling, insulting or mean. You disagree with my stance.. How can I explain that without you beating me with a rubber hose saying I am hostile because I disagree with you?

Comment: @Patrice you yourself suggested "hostility" – I just picked it up. As a member of the group hacking away, I guess you're not the one getting beaten.

Comment: @nicolbolas It has not been dealt with – you just tuned in to a part of the problem I wanted to discuss – the only regulatory part there was and the only part, where – of course – there is not really anything to discuss, because – of course – I violated an (extremely formal) rule.

Comment: I am the first one who used the word hostility, sure. But you're splitting hairs if you say I am the first one who brought the 'issue' forward regardless of the word being used. My main issue is again, I am trying to get better at these things. Please explain what reception would have made you see this differently? It feels like we just cannot disagree with your point, no matter how civil we are about it. The mere act of disagreeing is hostile.... That won't lead anywhere

Comment: @Mistercookiebite Ok, so you came here to discuss the rule, and you hear from answer, comments and links that writing comments as answers is wrong. What more do you want from us now? The rules won't change. It is unfortunate that you got a ban, though. What do you need? Tips on how to get out of a ban? A feature request to change the rules? No downvotes on meta? Can we help in any way? Are you open for suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid that to a martyr, every comment and disagreement is hostile. I'm gone. (my only truly hostile comment in this thread)

Comment: @Mistercookiebite You said that "It feels very hostile indeed". People here were nice to you and patiently discussed the problem with you. You said that you wanted to help people, please explain why this meta post was hostile and how is it possible to disagree with you without being hostile? It might actually be helpful.

Comment: @Mistercookiebite What?  They are called 'answers' and 'comments'.  It doesn't really even need a rule, 'extremely formal', or otherwise.  Comments are not answers.  You cannot walk in to a liquor store that has a 'Cash Only' sign and demand to pay with a card.  You might be a billionaire with your black Centurion card, you still won't get your six-pack, no matter how much you complain about hostile, unwelcoming staff:(

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'd argue that the downvotes on the non-answer were valid but not necessary in this particular case.  I wouldn't have downvoted because it looked like an honest (and potentially useful) attempt to help make SO better from someone who either didn't know better or didn't realize that we have to take the rules serious on a site with this many users.  I think just a comment + flag on the non-answer would have been sufficient to correct the user's future behaviour.  I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 16):

If I remember your answer correctly, there was another user and I who told you that your answer wasn't an answer. I posted a comment on your answer to explain that to you and I posted your answer as a comment for you. I think we have been nice to you.

Unfortunately, I can't see the question but my comment was an automatic comment:

> This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you
>   will be able to post comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For
>   the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post
>   for deletion.

I don't think there is anything rude.

Answer (score 13):

I think we've fairly conclusively established that your actions were against the rules, so I won't get into that.

But let's start a discussion, here; what would you like to see happen?  What can we do better about this experience?  Should we not enforce our rules on answers?  Can we explain the rules better?  Should we not downvote them?

There are plenty of things we can do.  The question is how those actions impact the overall quality of the site.  So let's hear your take on how to make it better.

Comment: I'd like to tack on 'how we could have expressed disagreement in this meta question without you thinking negatively about it?'

Comment: @Patrice I know this is an old comment, but for posterity, it sounds like you're assuming the OP's reaction is entirely his fault, which I don't think is a fair assumption

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have posted your comment as an answer, but **downvotes on that non-answer weren't *necessary***.  (But also not unexpected).  Not-an-answer flags + a comment should be sufficient to point new users in the right direction.

This is exactly the kind of case where we could simply *tell* an over-eager new user (who clearly made a real effort to help) that they need to wait until they have 50 rep before commenting, please don't make a mess this way.  Based on the fact that the comment included a link to a https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ Q&A (i.e. the user is looking around on stackexchange sites and will hopefully figure out how we do things), I would have given @Mistercookiebite the benefit of the doubt that a comment + not-an-answer flag -> deletion would avoid repeat offences of comments-as-answers.

Re: the mess: Notice that the clarifications from the OP of the DLL question ended up as comments on the non-answer, not under the question. We really want edits to the question, but at least comments under the question are better than under an answer that needs to be deleted.  It really did make a mess, and maybe hurt the chances of salvaging that unclear question more than it helped.)

It did lead to a mess, but **the non-answer comment was actually the most useful thing anyone had yet added to the question, to ask for specific clarification**.  It would have been actively *good* and helpful as a comment.  So it's very understandable for a beginner to want to bend/break the rules and post something helpful in those conditions.  (Doesn't mean you won't get downvotes.  And remember that votes aren't given for effort.)

If other comments had already requested more details (on this unclear question), there would have been much less excuse for bending the rules.

**The flaw in the above reasoning is that it would require checking someone's history to see if they'd already done this before, and still weren't learning**.  The C and C++ tags especially have a low tolerance for poor questions (and apparently poor answers), because they get a LOT of traffic.  Questions with both tags already put many people in a bad mood.

People aren't going take that much care to make sure you *really* deserve it before downvoting, especially when a post is obviously breaking the rules.  Moderating the site to encourage the contributions we want and discourage those we don't takes time, and people are in a hurry when voting, too.  Some people downvote even very good answers just because they're posted on bad questions, or IDK why.  A downvote or two isn't normally the end of the world.  (A temporary answer ban isn't the end of the world either; don't panic.)

**I suspect most users who saw the non-answer in the hour or 2 between posting and deletion decided not to downvote.  If it was actually bad as well as in the wrong place, it would have dropped much faster.**

The two downvotes this got before being deleted (from a review queue) only resulted in a ban because of other poorly-received posts, and you could have deleted it manually after it got the first downvote.  (You did know you were bending / breaking the rules and already had a previous downvoted question and answer, so it would have been a good idea to keep an eye on StackOverflow to see what happened here.  I'm not trying to blame you here; maybe you didn't realize this would attract downvotes, or that downvotes would lead to a temporary ban.  I'm pointing out other things you could have done, but maybe didn't realize at the time would have been a good idea.)

TL:DR: sit out your time in the penalty box and please try to find some good questions you can answer well, with clear explanations, to gain some rep before spending your time on questions that need improvement.

The SO system is designed this way to avoid a flood of noise from new users, because unfortunately a large fraction of new users are not interested in making helpful contributions the way you are.  **Please blame the help vampires and spammers that made us set up strict rules like this (with auto-bans and comment limits) and that taught us we need to aggressively downvote content that's doesn't belong.**

---

## For those who can't see deleted questions / answers:

question:

> -3 score (totally deserved the downvotes: no MCVE or any way to answer)
>
> I'm just curious to know how I can pack a DLL file so that it's hard
> to disassemble. It's in C++, but every time I try packing it, and I
> inject the DLL file into the game, it just crashes.
>
> The DLL is for a GTA V mod menu in which I developed.
>
> `[dll]`
>
> (before an edit by @Peter Mortensen, was also tagged `[c]` and `[c++]`)

- comment: Define "pack". Please.
- comment: Stargateur's repost of the non-answer as a comment.
- more noise

non-answer from Mistercookiebite

> -2 score
> What exact error message do you get when you run your game/your compiled code?
> Why do you need to "inject" the dll? usually, you need to inject something into a dll from the outside (in order to reverse-engineer it, see https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13599/how-to-manipulate-game-which-loads-many-dlls)

This *is* actually a useful comment, and even includes a link to a possibly-related Q&A.  The only problem here is that it was posted in the wrong place by an over-eager new user who doesn't know the ropes yet.

Obviously it shouldn't be upvoted, but I don't think it was necessary to downvote it, instead just flag it as not-an-answer.  (Especially after @Stargateur helpfully reposted it as a comment.)

At that point @Mistercookiebite should have deleted the non-answer if they get the notification from comments on the non-answer in time.  (IDK what order things happened.)