# I don't know the reason my answers were deleted. What should I do?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

A moderator ([@ChrisF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf)) deleted all my answers without any comments on why they are deleted. Here is an example answer:
[how do I calculate the geometric product of two vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378671/how-do-i-calculate-the-geometric-product-of-two-vectors/53672090#53672090)

As a new user with reputation below the threshold I cannot write in chat, I cannot comment on posts and I cannot post a on meta Stack Overflow.

What can I do in this case? Is there any way I can get some form of feedback on why my answers are deleted?

Comment: You're right, this belongs on the meta site, but I don't see anything so inherently bad about your deleted answer that it should be deleted.  Maybe the moderator saw a very erudite answer from someone with a very low rep, and assumed it was a prank or something.

Comment: And I certainly don't see how your answer was "spam or rude or abusive" in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: perhaps @ChrisF marked it as spam because I included a link to a python library that I use and contribute to?

Comment: I didn't add a disclaimer as it seems a bit much given I am not even the original author of it

Comment: You are the primary contributor, though, @HugoHadfield.

Comment: Were all those deleted answers individually written? Or are they mostly copy-pasted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable the “ask about own post” feature for low-rep users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/enable-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-for-low-rep-users)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as @Cerbrus. I have often seen copy-pasted answers placed on multiple questions, and in that situation flag the moderator since that too is considered "spam"

Comment: Here are my list of questions that were deleted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534093/how-can-geometric-algebra-blades-be-implemented-in-c/53671599#53671599

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378671/how-do-i-calculate-the-geometric-product-of-two-vectors/53672090#53672090

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108306/how-to-use-4d-rotors/53672204#53672204

granted they are of varying quality and all use the clifford library, to which in the last year or so I have contributed a lot although I definitely don't consider myself as the author of it

Comment: Some of those answers do appear to be low-quality mostly link answers, and so don't belong as written

Comment: Looks like you promoted your own library without disclosing it was yours.  That's a no-no on this site.  Doing that multiple times will get the answers spam flagged.

Comment: New answers by a new user on (some very) old questions linking to a library they're heavily involved in. On Stack Overflow, that draws some attention to your account. The questions were likely deemed to be "spam" or at least "advertising".

Comment: ah, ok yeah I can understand people's concerns there

Comment: I guess the correct thing to do is to add a disclaimer to my deleted answers saying I contribute to the library?

Comment: Yes, add a disclaimer, and make sure that the quality of the answer is such that it stands on its own.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice all :)

Comment: @HugoHadfield Even doing all that alone isn't enough.  You need to disclose affiliation, you need to ensure the answers stand alone without following links, and you shouldn't be bringing up a product you're affiliated with in a large portion of your answers (even if doing the previous two points), because that's *still* spamming. Just going around trying to find ways of bringing up a products you're affiliated with is called "astroturfing".

Comment: A good resource to read is, [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: How is any of this on-topic on SO though? Seems to be a pure math question?

Comment: question was deleted, only visible for 10k+ useres now. it was a pure math one, hence offtopic.

Comment: @Servy that's a little too generalistic. If someone is an expert on a tool they wrote and that tool is a perfect fit for many questions, should they answer 2 questions relating to whatever for every question they answer relating to what they actually know a  lot about? It's possible to bring up your tool in every single answer of yours and still contribute meaningful content to the site. It's not spam, if it's high quality, no matter how many of your answers relate to that tool. So no, that's not "still spamming".

Comment: @DonQuiKong And  yet that's not what the rules say.  The rules specifically say that that's spam, and not appropriate behavior.  See the help center page on how not to be a spammer for details.  If you want to change the rule, then replying to a comment of mine isn't the way to do that.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Oh, and if you create a new proposal to discuss this, a few points you're going to need to address in it are the fact that a large portion of people engaging in that type of behavior aren't in fact posting high quality content, they're just trying to post content that's not technically spam so a moderator won't delete it, and people affiliated with a product that are posting *good* answers about it tend to not have a problem posting about other topics as well, and only discussing their affiliated product when it comes up naturally in the course of answering questions.

Comment: @Servy so if I were a developer of a programming language I would not be allowed to answer questions on stackoverflow unless answering most of them about another programming language? You might be right in most cases, but no, the rules don't say that having an affiliation with something useful is spam.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I didn't say that.  But if you went around to various questions in other programming languages and started telling them about how much better their solutions would be in the programming language you're affiliated with, *that* would be spam.  Likewise, going around answering questions about a product you're affiliated with is fine, going around to questions *not* asking about your product, to tell them to use your product, *is not*.

Comment: @Servy well unless your product is actually a good (or the best, think numpy or whatever) solution to the problem. Thin line there though. Then we basically agree, I guess.

Comment: So Jon Skeet is not allowed to answer questions about NodaTime? I'm pretty sure he has not explicitly spelled out his relationship to it in every answer, perhaps because "Well everyone *knows that*...".

Comment: @mickeyf that's the thing. SO is filled with dogma.

Comment: @DonQuiKong If you're actually an expert on the tool because you made it, you're probably an expert on more than just that -- so you should try to contribute in the other areas you're an expert in, too. If all of your answers _are_ high-quality, then it's probably going to be allowed, but the vast majority of the time it's just "I made [this library] which does that exact thing, look at it", which is... subpar for other reasons besides.

Comment: @mickeyf Do you think the majority of Jon's posts involve going around to posts not about NodaTime and suggesting that NodaTime be used instead?  You'll note that on the rare occasions where Jon brings up NodaTime in a post not already about it he's good about explicitly noting his affiliation with the product.  Jon is well aware of this policy and makes sure to follow it carefully, hence his actions aren't spam.  Jon is a great example of why this policy *doesn't* inhibit people affiliated with a product from posting about it within the rules.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can go to the "contact us" page linked in the footer of every site.  Technically that's a way of contacting community managers, not regular moderators, but they would still be able to answer your question of why your posts were deleted.

You could flag one of your deleted questions saying you didn't understand why it was deleted.  Given that you don't have enough rep to post on meta or in chat (the two places I would normally suggest asking about this) that would probably be fine.  You might risk a declined flag, but that's not the end of the world.

The other option would be to just wait a little bit, earn the little bit of rep you need to post on meta or in chat, and use one of those two places, as those are generally the preferred ways to discuss an issue like this with a moderator.

Comment: You're forgetting one important thing: OP could have asked on meta even without the rep if they tried because they have a post on the main site. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366734/6083675) for more info.

Comment: @Laurel Does that work with deleted posts?

Comment: I would assume it does. It sounds like it was the case for [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366818/6083675), although I can't verify it due to being under 10k.

Comment: @Laurel That user had (and still has) 5 rep before posting their question, just looking at their reputation history.

Comment: "I have a question about my Stack Overflow post" and an HTML comment are automatically inserted into the question when the feature is used so they didn't when they posted that meta question (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/323179)).

Answer (score 73):

I didn't delete them "as spam", if I considered them spam I would have flagged them as such and they would have been shown as deleted by "Community" not me. You would have also suffered a 100 point reputation penalty on each answer.

They were *flagged* as spam and I deleted them because you hadn't declared your affiliation [first revision of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53672090/1)

Now that you have declared your affiliation they are no longer spam by Stack Overflow's definition.

The correct procedure is to flag the answer(s) stating that you've fixed the issue so that we (as a group) can review your edit and make sure that you have properly declared your affiliation.

In this case, it all appears nicely done so I'll go ahead and undelete the two that you've edited now.

There's nothing wrong in linking to your projects to illustrate solutions, but if **all** of your answers only exist to promote your projects then there's a good chance that they'll get flagged again and I can't guarantee that they won't be deleted again.

Comment: Great, thanks @ChrisF and apologies for not disclosing affiliation

Comment: Note, users without at least 15 reputation can't flag posts, any post.

Comment: @Braiam any registered user can always flag their own posts with the custom reason regardless of reputation.

Comment: @JonClements [Flagging is a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: I have accepted the answer of @Servy as I think it answers the general question of new users although this one clearly handles my case specifically, ChrisF I couldn't work out any easy way of getting in contact with you via easy means hence my posting like this

Comment: @Braiam flagging *other* posts is a privilege... you can always flag your *own* posts without that privilege but only with a custom reason. Similar to how you need 50 rep to comment anywhere, but you can always comment on your own questions/answers or on answers to questions you posted - but not anywhere else...

Comment: Did you leave a message for OP somewhere to clarify why you deleted the posts? Feels like this Meta question could have been avoided.

Comment: @yivi "status complete added Aug 10" "always". Yeah, about that...

Comment: @JonClements that's a new (like less than 4 months old) behavior and the help center doesn't say that it is possible.

Comment: @Braiam what I'm referring to is different... that opened up comment flagging which required the flagging privilege until then... you've always (or close enough to it) been able to flag your own question/answer with a custom flag regardless...

Comment: Incidentally, I ran into one of these answers in a low quality posts review audit and failed because of this. Couldn't figure out why the question was deleted until now.

Comment: @JonClements apparently a [undocumented feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228288/213575) then.

Comment: Just a quick question: is the « correct procedure to flag the answer(s) stating that you’ve fixed the issue » documented anywhere? And I’ll second @Stijn ‘s comment: was a message left indicating this?

Comment: Hi Chris. Given that this Meta question has popped up, it'd be better if you can inform the user, via either a comment or a mod message, about why and how to fix. This is just my humble opinion, though.