# Short question privilege to prevent new users from making low-quality questions

Tags: feature-request

With [the recent drama on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color), many have been racking their brain trying to find a solution to make everyone happy.

I came up with a fairly simple one which I think would greatly impact the situation we're having with some new users writing low-quality questions.

New users with less than a set amount of points, let's say 100, should be forced to have more words in their question.

#### Why not just all users?

Because short questions do not mean bad questions, but not everyone should be qualified to be allowed the **short question privilege**. Only after one has proven that he/she can operate within Stack Overflow until they reached 100 reputation should they be considered able to write a short, high quality question.

Coincidentally, when you reach 200 points, I believe you get a reputation boost of 100 on all other Stack Exchange sites, which could also grant the said privilege.

Also, a link to an article like Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) should also be at the bottom of question creation form to guide new users into creating a good question.

#### Complication

This is not foolproof; a user could still ask a question that is made up of 90% code, but it should still help guiding some new users into making higher quality questions.

## Update

It was worth a shot.

New users don't know the rules, adding an extra rule wouldn't make them respect the other rules more.

Comment: Drama? What drama? ;P

Comment: There's already an enforcement for a certain code/text ratio. The way users circumvent that is by filling their post with garbage. – This kind of thing simply doesn't work in the real world.

Comment: @yannis SO is getting a stage production, haven't you heard?

Comment: Cats run frequently on new SO users' keyboards for some weird reason.

Comment: I'd rather they post a short and bad question than a long and bad one. Waste less of people's time that way.

Comment: At least it's not about implementing this for the comments, thanks god.

Comment: @xoxel I wish you had not mentioned that.  Somebody will read that and put it forward as an actual proposal to try and force user-moderators to wast.. spend more time on 'nice', 'welcoming' comments:(

Comment: I just recently saw a question consisting of one sentence copied again and again until the character limit was reached.

Comment: @ModusTollens Yeah, it's not uncommon.  They usually get insta-closed, but it's annoying to see casual rule-avoidance like that:(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Question **length** does not correlate with question **quality**.

*Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Are we there yet? Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold. Padding to reach the word count threshold.*

Comment: if new user pad to reach threshold, they can't complain about their question being blocked, whereas closing for low quality question is harder for them to understand.

Comment: @TwiN: Considering the hoops users jump through to circumvent existing filters, I don't think the proposed system will be as effective as you hope it will be. Also, a short question _can_ be a very good one.

Comment: You're probably right.

Comment: @TwiN Also, some questions do not even need padding. Consider, for instance, "Debug this for me: [200-line code dump]".

Comment: @TwiN They would complain anyway.