# Was a user suspended for their political beliefs?

Tags: discussion, banning

On the Meta question [Does Stack Exchange really want to conflate newbies with women/people of color?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color), a user posted an answer that heavily criticized the recent blog post. He was temporarily banned a little while after. Was he banned for his political beliefs, or was it for some other reason? Are moderators or Stack Overflow employees really biased enough that they would ban someone for something like that?

Comment: Probably best to not try and go there.  No good will come of it if you do.

Comment: Why this person is suspended is, has been, and always will be between that person and Stack Overflow moderation.

Comment: Yeah..... It could be any number of things. Speculation won't be helpful and just bring more and more resentment....

Comment: SE isn't going to release any details about why someone else was suspended, for privacy reasons.  Oleg is the only one who can answer your question.

Comment: I think if you look at the revisions on the post and the arguments in comments you may see why... especially the one about reposing the comment that was removed.

Comment: We have no idea what happened.  It could be something in some comments wound up not being to nice for whatever reason and the moderator(s) felt he needed some time to cool down.  Lets not be so quick to light the torches and grab the pitchforks.  I get you're passionate but we need to also use restraint at times like these.

Comment: I highly doubt that, and the fact the the answer is still there also points to a big fat "no".

Comment: I agree this is not because of the answer, but probably because of the numerous comment posted by this user, however with this highly tension topic, I found the ban reason should be clear and open to the community. Who moderate the moderator... there is not a lot of counter power in SO.

Comment: We as a community has elected those moderators, I feel that gives quite a bit of balance to moderation on SO. Beyond that, SO has allowed quite a lot of highly critical opinions lately and I'm having a hard time believing they'd go after this specific user over that. If someone is not capable of disagreeing in a civil manner, that's another story but we don't know exactly what happened here since deleted comments aren't visible.

Comment: It should also be noted that the "little while after" was (based on the time when the suspension ends and the user posting comments) several *days* after that post. It is extremely unlikely that the user was suspended for that answer.

Comment: i mean... it wouldn't surprise me if he was.  People are being suspended for not speaking in a way that appeases the PC crowd on the grounds of  not following the "be nice" policy.

Comment: Why are people so quick to jump on the "OMG, political suppression!!" bandwagon, given that there is clear evidence all around that SO isn't, in fact, suppressing dissenting views? (See also: claiming that not opening the blog post for comments was a way of precluding discussion... in a comment to one of the dozens of Meta questions that discusses the blog post.)

Comment: (By the way, by "bandwagon" I don't refer to the mere existence of this post, but to how the very loaded way it frames the matter -- cf. the question it has as its final sentence -- has not stopped it from getting 17 upvotes as of now.)

Comment: My best guess is that discrediting "the other side" has become a popular way to approach a subject lately. It's why we have terms like "PC" and "alt-right" being thrown around as pejoratives. Sadly, we live in a time of polarization and it's becoming increasingly difficult to discuss stuff. With a few exceptions I'm actually very impressed with how things have been going on meta after "the blog post". I've learned a lot by lurking most of the recent high-traffic posts and seen well presented arguments on both sides. Let's try to keep it like that.

Comment: @KevinB it's pretty clear if you read the thread and comments the user was banned for adding and re-adding comments and arguing after they were removed. The unnecessary political undertones of your comment are similar to those same comments. Call it "PC" but I feel like SO is not the place for political discussion.

Comment: @JacobH "I feel like SO is not the place for political discussion". Ha. If SO doesn't wan't political discussions, they shouldn't have posted the blog.

Answer (score 28):

We [try to avoid discussing specific suspensions publicly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions), *particularly* while the relevant user is still suspended. It's unfair to the person who was suspended and unable to defend themselves.

We also discourage folks from [calling out specific users by name here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289909/should-any-meta-post-that-calls-out-a-user-by-name-be-deleted-not-just-downvote), for pretty much the same reason.

So I've edited your question, and I'm not going to say anything specific to this user's suspension.

I will note, for the benefit of one and all, that while anyone is free to discuss controversial topics here the [be nice](/help/be-nice) policy still applies; if you can't [show basic respect to the folks who disagree with you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289398/if-youre-gonna-talk-politics-you-must-respect-those-who-disagree), then there's no point in talking to them at all.

Comment: I wish that the Stack Exchange policy was instead to *ask* suspended users whether they are happy to have the reason for their suspension made public, rather than making that choice for them. Preventing a user's suspension from being discussed *even if that user wants it to be* doesn't protect their privacy, it just protects SE and the mods from criticism. As for this particular case, I have no idea what Oleg wants, but I don't think the *process* by which you're getting to this decision is quite the right one.

Comment: Nothing stops the user from coming back and talking about their suspension here after it has expired, @Mark. Heck, nothing stops them from talking about it anywhere else while they're still suspended. Both of those things happen fairly often, and if the user themselves rejects the courtesy of discretion that we extend to them we're usually more'n happy to air all the dirty laundry that they can eat. But... we do try to be courteous by default, and I think that's a good policy for all the reasons Jon stated in the first link above.

Comment: @Shog9 well when the period is long what you say don't work, specially for life ban account...

Comment: @Shog9 *"air all the dirty laundry that they can eat"* is a rather troubling mixed metaphor for anyone who is not a moth. As for the rest - well, I shall wait and see what happens in a few months.

Comment: I've never banned anyone for life, @Stargateur. I have had people die on me, but I've tried to work with them to get 'em back on the site for as long as I was able. If the user in question doesn't expect to live beyond July, they should definitely be willing to work this out.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the "anyone is free to discuss controversial topics here " policy is no longer in effect, this could get people finding this in 2020 in trouble.

Comment: Trying to guess at what won't get people in trouble in 2020 isn't a game I want to play, @patrick. I think my advice here is as reasonable now as it was when I wrote it; if it doesn't work out here in practice, then maybe this is not as good a place to be as it was in 2018.

Answer (score 13):

I'm going to let the employee that enforced the suspension chime in on the particulars, though we can't share very much about it.

I want to take a moment and clearly say that we would not suspend anyone for their beliefs, or the expression of those beliefs, as long as they were expressed in a manner that is consistent with our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

We provide this platform *for you to disagree with us* if that's what you want to do. We just ask that you do it with respect and sincerity for us as well as other users.

Comment: The problem is now that SO is become politic the ban policy is going to become a recurrent problem, however I believe in SO staff... so I have no doubt you have ban this user for a very good reason ;)

Comment: SO has not become political in the manner I suspect you mean @Stargateur; it has *always* been political in the sense that there are certain positions that the staff holds and that the policies (and moderators) enforce.

Comment: @TylerH I don't agree, SO politics has always been focus about the site and the site only, nothing else. Be nice was a general rule for everyone. No exception even if linus will come to answer question in SO, we will ban him every month ;). And now we talk, talk, talk about this sujet since days... It's even more visible that I think nobody never see the meta like that before. But I stop the "off-topic" here, no need to spam this answer ;)

Comment: @Stargateur And "be nice" is still the scope of politics here. It doesn't matter what someone is talking about, real world politics, religion, human rights, etc., it's still under the "Be Nice" umbrella *as Tim Post says in the answer*.

Comment: I wouldn't say that SO "becoming politic" is a problem; everyone has a political position, even if it's just "maintain the status quo." I'd say a bigger trust issue exists because a community moderator can post a [ranting diatribe on MSO, leave it up for 12 hours,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/366969/1) and not get sanctioned in the slightest. *That* is the sort of thing that erodes trust in community moderators.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not _visibly_ sanctioned. I think that's important to point out, especially in the context of us just talking about how we don't like to put laundry out in the air. I'm just going to leave that there.

Comment: Wait, 100+ downvotes and 4 closes doesn't count as a "visible sanction"? What more do we need, a [stone of shame?!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJW8Y.png)

Comment: @Shog9: The comments section is not suitable for feature requests. Please post a new question for your suggestion ;)

Comment: @Shog9 wow didn't know this question of Yvette, actually If it was me who wrote this post I think I would have be ban for one week... at least for "cold down" (this is maybe the best ban reason in the world) !

Comment: Y'all seem to think we ban people for a lot less than is actually the case. Everyone makes mistakes; most of us learn from them and move on.